# Package or namespace failed

Tags: r

I'm trying to install the package 'microdadosBrasil' but I am with some problems. After the install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github("lucasmation/microdadosBrasil")
The program asks me to update de version and here commes the error:

```
It is recommended to update all of them.
Which would you like to update?

1: All                           
2: CRAN packages only            
3: None                          
4: Rcpp (1.0.4 -> 1.0.4.6) [CRAN]

Enter one or more numbers, or an empty line to skip updates:
1
...
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
*** arch - i386
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'microdadosBrasil' in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib):
 DLL 'datatable' not found: maybe not installed for this architecture?
Erro: loading failed
Execução interrompida
*** arch - x64
ERROR: loading failed for 'i386'
* removing 'C:/Users/Usuario/OneDrive/Documentos/R/win-library/3.6/microdadosBrasil'
Erro: Failed to install 'microdadosBrasil' from GitHub:
  (convertido do aviso) installation of package ‘C:/Users/Usuario/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpOO4bHT/file3a0479d3ee9/microdadosBrasil_0.0.0.9000.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had that error on a few occasions. Usually using manually installing the package that R is stumbling over is sufficient to get past that point.

So I would try `install.packages('i386')` and if you get an error on that package, it may be informative. Often they are tied to underlying language interpreters or some kind of application you need installed.

If you see that error on the dependency keep drilling down until you find the root cause of the failure. Once you get that package or underlying language or application installed, you can work your way back up and all will be right in the world.

Comment: i386 is probably rather the hardware architecture. From the error message I would try `install.packages('datatable')` instead

Comment: it could be @PierreGramme, I have had both issues. But I can often chase down dependencies to get past it.